# Is there a function to insert the correct `(kbd "...")` by pressing the key?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm bored of looking up key names for the `kbd` function, is there a way to automatically insert the correct key name just by pressing the key?

So for example I want something to do this: I'm typing

```
(local-set-key |
```

I run `magical-insert-kbd-command`, press f6 and I get

```
(local-set-key (kbd "<f6>") |
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are asking. But `C-h k` followed by hitting the key shows you exactly what string you need to pass to `kbd`. For example, `C-h k f6` shows you `<f6>`.

Here is a command that does what you want, I guess and binds the result to `C-c c`:

```el
(defun foo (key)
  (interactive "kKey: ")
  (insert (format "(kbd %S)" (key-description key))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'foo)
```

Then type:

```
(local-set-key C-c c
```

That prompts you to use a key.  If you hit the <kbd>F6</kbd> key then you get this:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "<f6>")
```

---

[Updated per suggestion by @HaraldHancheOlsen: Changed `"(kbd \"%s\")"` to `".](kbd %S)"`

Comment: Perfect, thanks!. The main thing I was missing was missing the `key-description` function.

Comment: But OP is right that it would be a useful to have a function that automatically placed the keybinding in the kill ring.

Comment: @incandescentman: Huh? Where does the OP say anything about the *kill ring*? And just what do you mean by the "keybinding" in that sentence? A key binding is not a string, which is what the `kill-ring` contains. Do you mean the `key-description` string? or the return value of the above `format` sexp? Anyway, it should be clear how to modify the command I gave, to add either of those to the `kill-ring` (just use `kill-new`).

Comment: "automatically insert." If I understand correctly, the solution above only displays the keybinding (e.g. `kbd <M-return>`) but does not insert it into an init file. (You'd have to do the additional step of copy/paste.) Maybe I misunderstood. For my own personal use case, I would find it useful to have a way to query the syntax for a keybinding (e.g. is the syntax `M-RET` or `M-<return>` or what?) and automatically place that string in the kill ring/pasteboard, so that I could then paste the keybinding into my init file when writing a line like `(define-key map (kbd "<M-return>") 'org-return)`.

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood. (But there was also a typo in the key-binding sexp: I forgot to use `kbd` in the `global-set-key` sexp - corrected now.) Command `foo` (which the `global-set-key` sexp binds to `C-c c`) reads a key sequence and then inserts, at point of the current buffer, the proper `kbd` sexp for it. If you use `C-c c` in your init file, after `(local-set-key `, then it inserts the `kbd` sexp you need for the key it reads.

Comment: @incandescentman: See my previous comment. I think the code should do what you want. You want to be able to hit the key to see what the correponding `kbd` sexp would be. It does that. It inserts that sexp in the current buffer at point.

Comment: Nice. but I think using `(format "(kbd %S) …)"` is more robust. It will escape any `"` (or backslashes, etc.) in the key sequence provided.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Good point! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Drew In my config, I named the function `keybinding-read-and-insert`.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `M-x local-set-key` to do your keybinding interactively, you can use `C-x ESC ESC` (`repeat-complex-command`) to get a Lisp expression that you can paste into your config. It probably won't use friendly `(kbd ...)`-style descriptions, though.

Comment: Neat. I tend to use `define-key` though actually, it seems simpler to just define the key outright than to set up a hook to call a function to define the key.