# How to get the string representation of a keymap event?

Tags: string, events

I'd like to get the string representation of a keymap event. For instance `19` should be printed as `C-s`, `1` as `C-a` etc...

I could make my own function to do that but since `describe-key`is capable of printing the string representation of an event there must be a built-in function to do that somewhere. I looked into the manual and browsed some code and was not able to found it.

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12906/115

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a single key/character, just use function `single-key-description`.

```
(single-key-description 19) ; => "C-s"
```

If a list of characters, convert them to a string and use function `key-description`.

```
(key-description (string 19 25 20 5 43)) ; => "C-s C-y C-c C-e +"
```

If a key sequence as a string, use function `key-description`.  (Here I write `"^Y"` etc when I mean the string with a single control char, `^Y`.)

```
(key-description "^S^Y^T^e+") ; => "C-s C-y C-c C-e +"
```